# Remove system menu bar from react native android app

Tags: android, menu, react-native

My problem is simple and I have been unable to find a solution. The menu bar is very annoying in my app and I am hoping that there is a way to remove it. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`Hiding the Navigation Bar`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/system-ui/navigation.html) I found this:

> You can hide the navigation bar on Android 4.0 and higher using the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION flag. This snippet hides both the navigation bar and the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
          | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

I do not know if that's exactly what you was looking for, but you can test it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This let me to discover [immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/system-ui/immersive.html) which I think is what I want, however I am in react native so not sure how to access the View, but I will prevail.

Comment: @joemillervi - I am also looking out for a solution to this issue using React Native. Let me know if you find a resolution.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read more about native modules, it enables you to write native code and access it from JS.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content

Also the StatusBar module is very similar to what you want to do here, you can have a look at the source.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/statusbar/StatusBarModule.java#L110

Comment: Thanks that's what I did I added:
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);     It gets rid of the nav bar but react native does not recalculate the screen size so there is just blank white space where the nav bar was. Any idea about that?

Comment: Try calling
ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(activity.getWindow().getDecorView());

Like here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/statusbar/StatusBarModule.java#L102